# PageObjectModel vs ExcelBased Selenium Framework

Tags: java, c#, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

What are the pros and cons of each framework? Our team is deciding which framework to use for our next project.

The first framework PGO starts with the programmer creating a test. This is the test object. After creating the test, we implement the framework by creating a class/method that will make that test method pass and then refactor, which will be the page object. The classes will expose methods that let the QA tester test particular fields such as setFirstName(firstName) and setEmail(email) etc. The framework has not been started yet.

The second framework revolves around a Excel spread sheet. The already created Framework will read all the columns and rows of three excel spreadsheets and use them to automate through test cases. The first spread sheet is how to identify the test case. The second spread sheet are the steps and what parameters to include, and the third spread sheet are the actual parameters used. To identify each test case through the three excel sheets, an ID is used. These excel sheets are manually typed in as input.

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not like Excel based framework. I will tell you why.

With Selenium we mostly use TestNG, NUnit, JUnit etc. depending on the language bindings. Those frameworks are well maintained and well tested.
If we are talking about the same things then the Excel based framework has all the controlling power of the test execution which can be really disturbing in terms of maintenance. If you read about [Page Object model](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) you would see the separation of concern, refactoring and debugging are always the biggest concerns for UI test suite and this model handles them in the best manner. While using Excel based concept you are throwing the concept of pageobject out the window. Any changes/fixes on pages make you dig through all three excel sheet and find out the Selector and correct them. While in pageobject you know where to look. And, in terms of adding or removing any tests(which I do frequesntly) you can just go to the Test object then do it without affecting any other tests. On the other hand, removing/adding a test case can badly affect the entire test suite which I hate most.

Comment: Would you say that the Excel based framework would be worth pursuing if all the QAs were non-programmers? All programmers who are offshore are currently busy at the moment and they are not able to create the framework. That is the main reason for wanting to stick with their Excel based framework. I am their summer intern and I would be able to work on the PGO framework for a few more weeks. When the offshore is done being busy doing training etc, they will start selenium testing. As far as I know, there is no deadline for the automated testing framework. Btw I'd up vote you if I could

Comment: No, I would not. Designing PageObject framework is little bit of work at the beginning. But, maintaining and writing tests require the least amount of programming. I would at some cases very least